# CSS shake/jitter bug in chrome? transition of width on centered div

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have a centered div layer using `margin: 0 auto`, with a fixed width of `width: 1000px`, which will go `width: 100%` when starting to scroll down, along with a transition to make it look nice.

The problem is, that some of the content starts to shake and jitter during the transition. I say some of the content, because for example images shake, while H1 texts does not
This only happens in Chrome and Edge. (tested on windows 10).

Doing some research, I found Chrome had known issues in the past with transitions when not using hardware acceleration, resulting in flickering. From what I understand, this has been solved by Google over 2 years ago.

I tried implementing all sorts of workarounds, trying to trigger a hardware acceleration, but nothing worked.

From what I learned so far, this jittering / shaking issue only happens when a div layer is centered using `margin: 0 auto` with a fixed width and that element is then transitioned into `width: 100%`.

A strange issue, when re-creating the demo code inside of JSFiddle, I can’t seem to always reproduce it on my system.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aobrien/vc4n8ecy/

Just scroll down and notice how the chrome logo shakes. You might have to scroll up and down to noticed it, depending on your screen size.

Note: This only seems to be visible when you have a screen width of around 1700px or higher, so make sure your browser is in full width. Scaling the browser window to 80% also triggers the issue.

```js
//jQuery to add sticky class when scrolling

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('.header').addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    $('.header').removeClass("sticky");
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.header {
  background: #335C7D;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  transition: width .6s ease;
  height: 200px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  will-change: width;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="wrap">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaYsc.png" />
      <h1> Hello World.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This seems to be very easy and straight forward way of achieving a full width sticky menu with transition.

Could it be that using `margin: 0 auto` along with a width change, results in problems to recalculate the centered div layer?

So far, all my attempts to solve this or find a workaround, have failed.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, considering it's a legit CSS bug with chrome, and no one seems to have mentioned it anywhere, or even found a workaround.

Comment: Sometimes I'd like to punch those people in the face who down vote for no reason. This is a real bug in chrome/css which has not yet been reported, and zero people across the internet are talking about it. Instead of helping to find a workaround, people just downvote. Love the community here.

Comment: I  now  have  a similar issue with a curtain overlay that make Google Chrome's screen shake when I change the width of the overlay with javascript (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979458/google-chrome-screen-shakes-when-changing-element-width-with-javascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I found one solution.

Adding `display: table;` to the element that uses the `transition` property, seems to remove the shaking.

```js
//jQuery to add sticky class when scrolling

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('.header').addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    $('.header').removeClass("sticky");
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.header {
  background: #335C7D;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  transition: width .6s ease;
  height: 200px;
  display: table; /* this seems to fix it */
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  will-change: width;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="wrap">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaYsc.png" />
      <h1> Hello World.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```